# How to check Zend_Http_Client is available on server

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-http-client

Sorry I'm not familiar with php and I have to send something via `Zend_Http_Client`. How I can check that feature is available on server, because at the moment I've only got error 500.

Comment: you could try either `class_exists`, `method_exists` or `function_exists` - whichever is more pertinent to `Zend_Http_Client` ~ I don't know if it is a class or method etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check if ZF is available in your project libraries.
For Ubuntu, ZF should be in one of those:

- /usr/share/zend/
- /usr/share/php/
- /usr/local/zend/

or in your project directory.

In ZF "Zend_Http_Client", means that in your library directory you should have this folder structure: (...)/Zend/Http/Client/

Comment: thx i dont have such a previligies have to ask admin about it

Answer (score 1):

`Zend_Http_Client` is not a "feature", but a class from the Zend Framework library. In short is a set of classes that you can use as a whole or in parts to help you speed the development of your project. It offers solutions in a lot of common scenarios, and [Zend_Http_Client](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.http.client.html) is actually part of an interface that will help you work with HTTP requests. 
Check the requirements for it [here](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/requirements.introduction.html) and how to install it [here](https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/introduction.installation.html). The most common way is to add the library to the PHP [include_path](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) or to add it via [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to your project.